# How does javascript's referrer property work under the hood

Tags: javascript, http-headers, http-referer

How does javascript's `referrer` property work? Does it simply checks the http header data and outputs what it found there?

The referer property is accessed in the following way:

```
var ref = document.referrer;
console.log(ref);
```

Also, I noticed that the http referer `(Chrome Dev Tools->Network->Top HTTP Request->Referer)` is often stripped to only domain name without any subdomains. For example if an user has come from `www.facebook.com/stackoverflow`, his referer is always just `www.facebook.com`. Why is that so?

Comment: Always read the docs... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Comment: Thank you! I didn't found the information I was looking for at the page you linked.  To be exact, it doesn't state how it got the referer under the hood(did it look into the headers?). It just states what it is. URI can be both www.facebook.com or www.facebook.com/stackoverflow. So I still don't know what the correct answer. I am sorry if the question seems to easy to answer to you, but due to inexperience I cannot come up with a good explanation.

Comment: The `document.referrer` property literally returns the Response Header Referrer value. Here's an example of me visiting this page from google: `DNT: 1 Referer: https://www.google.co.uk/ Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch`

Comment: @evolutionxbox To my understanding, it doesn't. It returns the **Request** Header Referrer value.

Comment: @Federico there’s no distinction in the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20090303/html.html#ID-95229140. Maybe it’s not specifically the header value or the response value.

Comment: @evolutionxbox In practice, most browsers return the referrer from the request, not from the response. I think this might be due to the fact that Javascript doesn't have access to any header information from an HTTP response.

Comment: @Federico I got a comment on my answer a few years ago: _"the response header referer" — It's a request header, not a response header_ - turns out I updated the answer to show that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I know. I am leaving the comment for the ones (like me) that don't scroll down and will likely be very puzzled when the correct referrer doesn't  show in their code (like me ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Remember to always read the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

The `document.referrer` property literally returns a string from the **Request Header**.

Here's an example of me visiting this page from google:

```
GET /questions/36609134/how-does-javascripts-referrer-property-work-under-the-hood HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: https://www.google.co.uk/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
```

For more information on the request header **referer** visit [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

Comment: Thank you again! Google usually has query strings attached. Those are always removed from the referrer. Which is kinda logical. What about if you would come to this question from faceboook.com/SOquestion subdomain, than the subdomain is also stripped away.  Is there an explanation why subdomains are removed from referrer? Is that simply a convention folks stick to?

Comment: I don't think it's a convention. Have a look at Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) as it goes into detail on the http referer value.

Comment: "The document.referrer property literally returns a string from the Response Header" — That is not what the documentation you linked to says. The only evidence you've provided shows that, given common conditions (exceptions might exist), the values are the same.

Comment: "the response header referer" — It's a request header, not a response header.